# BST find() method only gives true when node is found

Tags: java, find, binary-search-tree

I am currently trying to implement a Binary Search Tree and so far, the only big problem I have is the find() method, since I have the problem, that I don't get any answer back, when I am looking for a key, which is not in my tree...
This is my code so far:

```
public class Bst {

Node root;
Node head;
Node tail;


public Bst(){
    root = null;
}

public void insert (Node root, int key){
    Node newNode=new Node(key);

    if(root==null){
        root=newNode;
    }

    if(key<=root.getKey()){
        if (root.getLeft()!=null){
            insert(root.getLeft(), key);
        }
        else{
            root.setLeft(newNode);
        }
    }

    if (key>=root.getKey()){
        if (root.getRight()!=null){
            insert(root.getRight(),key);
        }

        else{
            root.setRight(newNode);
        }

    }


    }

public void printTree(Node root){
    if (root==null) return;
    printTree(root.getLeft());
    System.out.print(root.getKey() + " ");
    printTree(root.getRight());
}

public Node treeToCDLL(Node root){
    if (root == null){
        return null;
    }

    Node leftTree=treeToCDLL(root.getLeft());
    Node rightTree=treeToCDLL(root.getRight());


    if (leftTree == null){
        head=root;
    }

    else {
        head=leftTree;
        leftTree.getLeft().setRight(root);
        root.setLeft(leftTree.getLeft());
    }

    if (rightTree==null){
        head.setLeft(root);
        root.setRight(head);
        tail=root;
    }

    else{
        tail=rightTree.getLeft();
        head.setLeft(tail);
        tail.setRight(head);
        root.setRight(rightTree);
        rightTree.setLeft(root);
    }

    return head;
}

public boolean find(Node root, int key){
    Node current=root;

    while(current!=null){

        if(current.getKey()==key){
            return true;
        }
        else if(current.getKey()>key){
            current=current.getLeft();
        }

        else
            current=current.getRight();
        }
    return false;
}

public void printList(Node head){
    Node current = head;

    while(current!=null){
        System.out.print(current.getKey() + " ");
        current=current.getRight();
        if(current==head) break;
    }
}
public static void main (String[]args){

    Bst bst=new Bst();

    Node root=new Node(4);
    bst.insert(root, 2);
    bst.insert(root, 1);
    bst.insert(root, 3);
    bst.insert(root, 5);
    bst.insert(root, 6);

    System.out.print("in-order traversal: ");
    bst.printTree(root);
    System.out.println();



    System.out.print("circular doubly linked list: ");
    Node head= bst.treeToCDLL(root);
    bst.printList(head);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Der gesuchte Knoten : " + bst.find(root,6));







}

}
```

I would be really happy, if you could help me, since I tried a lot of ways and it looks like I only get an answer, when I am looking for a key, which exists in the tree

Comment: What is the output you are getting for this code?

Comment: So do you mean when you search for a key that is not in the BST, it doesn't print false?

Comment: Do the `.getLeft()` and `.getRight()` actually return null?

Comment: You are converting your BST to a circular doubly linked list before you call `find()`. By definition this will go on forever searching (if the node doesn't exist) unless you mark nodes you've visited.

Comment: hey alex, perfect ;) that was the problem :D now everything seems to be ok, I am calling the method before I transform the tree to a list
thx and problem solved ;)

Comment: @ChthonicProject moved to answers.

Comment: @user3683131 no problem. I've moved my comment to an answer. Please mark it as correct (after time limit) if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting your BST to a circular doubly linked list before you call `find()`. By definition this will go on forever searching (if the node doesn't exist) unless you mark nodes you've visited.

Answer (score 0):

Your `find()` method looks fine. One problem I can see is you are converting your BST to Circular Linked List by calling

```
 Node head= bst.treeToCDLL(root);
```

before calling `find()`, that's why your program is going to infinite loop.

try `find(7)` before calling `bst.treeTOCDLL(root)`, it gives you false.